# Incorrect component scope inside a $route watch function on VueJs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

all.

I'm working on an app where I need to load/change data according to the app route path.

To know when the url has been changed I've added a `watch` function to the `$route` and I want to call a function in the same component to load data, all works the only thing is the scope of `this` inside the `watch` function instead of referred to the **VueComponent** instance is returning another object.

Here is my simplified code to get an idea

component.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="lists">
    {{pageTitle}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'lists',
    data() {
      return {
        pageTitle: 'Some Title',
      };
    },
    created() {
      console.log('LOAD THE ASKED PATH');
      console.log(this.$route.params); /* Object */
      console.log(this); /* VueComponent Instance */
    },
    watch: {
      $route: (value) => {
        console.log('ROUTE CHANGED');
        console.log(value); /* Route Object */
        console.log(this); /* NOT A VueComponent */
        this.pageTitle = 'Some new title';
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

This is the object I get for `this` inside the `watch` function

```
{default: {…}, __esModule: true}
default : beforeCreate : [ƒ]
beforeDestroy : [ƒ]
created : ƒ created()
data : ƒ data()
name : "lists"
render : ƒ ()
staticRenderFns : []
watch : {$route: ƒ}
_Ctor : {0: ƒ}
__file : "../my-app/src/components/Lists.vue"
__proto__ : Object
```

Not sure if this approach is correct or what I'm missing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use arrow functions to define watch handlers (or methods, or computed values, or lifecycle methods, etc). Arrow functions bind `this` lexically, and they cannot be re-bound.

Instead, just use a regular function. Vue will bind it to the Vue.

```
watch:{
  $route: function(value){
    console.log('ROUTE CHANGED');
    console.log(value); /* Route Object */
    console.log(this); /* NOT A VueComponent */
    this.pageTitle = 'Some new title';
  }
},
```